# How to run C# application EXE with normal user account? I don't want to provide Admin user name and password when UAC is on

Tags: c#, uac

I am working on the C# application. I am logged in to my machine with normal user account who don't have admin rights and UAC is set to highest level (Always notify me). When I try to run the application it ask me admin user name and password.I don't want to turn off the UAC. I have changed manifest file value to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

or

```
  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

But that din't help me. How can I run my application without full admin rights user? Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks:
Mayuresh

Comment: This isn't helpful but I would go to your IT department. A developer should always have local admin :(

Comment: I am developing it. I want some solution through coding that will help me to run the application without full admin rights to user.

Comment: Have you tried to remove that line at all? Or to comment it out?

Comment: UAC appears because you try to do something which requires admin rights. That is the purpose of UAC. If it was possible to bypass UAC, all malware would do it. Stop doing the thing that requires admin rights.

Comment: @Gusdor, he got admin rights but he is developing in a non-admin account. I do the same thing for this exact reason. I get notified immediately if my application doesn't work in a non-admin account.

Comment: Any idea what is being referenced that requires the privilages?

Comment: Did you tried with clickonce deployment approach, It might be worth if you imporsonate the user(admin) for installation, then the application will be available to install for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

From Project -> Project Properties and Application tab, just check whether your app.manifest file got referred under Icon and Manifest field or not, since it may be embedded also.